# How to register for custom push notifications in iOS9.3.5?

Tags: ios, push-notification

This is how my app was registering for push notifications.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

//REGISTER FOR THE NOTIFICATIONS TYPES
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
//-- Set Notification
if ([application 
respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    _storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

}

 _storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];


if (launchOptions != nil)
{
    NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (dictionary != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary);
        /*[self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:dictionary updateUI:NO];*/
    }
}
return YES;
}
```

When running the app, Im echoing the device tokens to make sure what's what.

[image]

When testing the 6.1 build on my iPhone running 7.1.2 (11D257) the app registers for notifications fine and echoes the device token when a user uploads a pic. But when I run it on my iPad Version 9.3.5 (13G36) the XCode console says `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later.` and the pic that was uploaded to iPad just shows a 0 where the device token should be.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
   if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```

I hope it helps you.